# Loading Access data to SQL Server

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

My aim is to update some fields in SQL Server 2008 R2 database from an Access database 2007

I created an  ssis package using an Access source which is mapped to network drive, I shared the database

The package executes fine in ssis.

I have to run job for scheduling, and when I run this in SQL Agent job it gets an error shown below

> Date,Source,Severity,Step ID,Server,Job Name,Step
>   Name,Notifications,Message,Duration,Sql Severity,Sql Message
>   ID,Operator Emailed,Operator Net sent,Operator Paged,Retries Attempted
>   03/02/2015 12:48:53,test_job,Error,0,PAVAN,test_job,(Job outcome),,The
>   job failed.  The Job was invoked by User PAVAN.  The last step to run
>   was step 1 (testjob_step).,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0
>
> 03/02/2015
>   12:48:53,test_job,Error,1,PAVAN,test_job,testjob_step,,Executed as
>   user: PAVAN\sys-32. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility 
>   Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation
>   2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:48:53 PM  Error: 2015-03-02 12:48:54.93     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: FirstPackage Connection
>   manager "\RAGHU-PC\vijay\access db\weighbridge.mdb"     Description:
>   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
>   Office Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The
>   Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the
>   file '\RAGHU-PC\vijay\access db\weighbridge.mdb'. It is already
>   opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view
>   and write its data.".  End Error  Error: 2015-03-02 12:48:54.93
>   Code: 0xC020801C     Source: datafor sqlserver OLE DB Source [1]
>   Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "\RAGHU-PC\vijay\access db\weighbridge.mdb" failed with error code
>   0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End
>   Error  Error: 2015-03-02 12:48:54.93     Code: 0xC0047017     Source:
>   datafor sqlserver SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "OLE DB
>   Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End
>   Error  Error: 2015-03-02 12:48:54.93     Code: 0xC004700C     Source:
>   datafor sqlserver SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component
>   failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2015-03-02 12:48:54.93     Code:
>   0xC0024107     Source: datafor sqlserver      Description: There were
>   errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:48:53 PM 
>   Finished: 12:48:54 PM  Elapsed:  0.936 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.,00:00:01,0,0,,,,0

Comment: Is there a chance that `\RAGHU-PC\vijay\access db\weighbridge.mdb is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view and write its data?` It looks like the Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file

Comment: Why so many down votes? Looks legit to me.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the above, make sure whoever has Access open did not open it via a shortcut that in the command line has /excl in it, which opens it exclusively and maybe locking this data pump.

Also just for kicks and giggles try running the SSIS package with nobody in it.

Also make sure \RAGHU-PC\vijay\access db\weighbridge.mdb is a valid path **on the server where the SSIS package is executed**, just it case that is not a correct mapping.

Comment: I'm sure the path is valid path with the same path it is executing in SSIS PACKAGE,While running the same package in sql agent job it is showing the error,if i take the source file locally the job get success.....

Comment: i want to take source from another system for that i use MAP NETWORK SHARING ,While running the job it gets an error shown above